# mvc3 jquery mobile how to use Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have already written an entire site in MVC3.  I am trying to build the mobile version with Jquery Mobile. I haven't changed my controller code, except to add a check for whether or not it should return a mobile page.  I have the following in the document head of my mobile logon page:

```
<head>
    <title>Mobile Logon</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.extend(  $.mobile , {
    ajaxEnabled: false
  });
});

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I have a page with a header and content.  In the content, I want to let the user redirect to the register form.  the following seems to work:

```
<form action="Register" method="get" data-ajax="false">           
    <button type="submit" value="Register for an account"></button>
</form>
```

This does not work: (the url seems correct in the browser, but all that loads is a blank, white page)

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Get, null ))
{
    <button type="submit" value="Register for an account"></button>  
}
```

When I look in the page source, I notice two differences: The first one gives a form tag with

```
action="Register"
```

while the second gives a form tag with

```
action="Account/Register"
```

The other difference is the "data-ajax=false" in the form tag.

Questions: 
Am I able to use @Html.BeginForm() with Jquery Mobile?  If not, how do I redirect to a different controller?

How come my code in the head section doesn't turn off the default ajax behavior of Jquery Mobile?  (I tried using the form tag above without data-ajax=false, and I got the same blank, white screen as the @Html.BeginForm gave me).

EDIT:  here is my logon controller code (Account controller)

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        //return View();
        return SelectView("Logon", null);
    }

    private ActionResult SelectView(string viewName, object model, string outputType = "html")
    {
        if (outputType.ToLower() == "json")
        {
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
#if MOBILE
  return View(viewName + ".Mobile", model);
#else
            if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
            {
                return View(viewName + ".Mobile", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return View(viewName, model);
            }
#endif
        }
    }
```

here is my Register controller code:  (Account controller)

```
    public ActionResult Register(string returnUrl = "")
    {
        //if no return url supplied, use referrer url.
        //Protect against endless loop by checking for empty referrer.
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Register", new { returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() });
        }                       

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What are the produced URLs from both of your examples? The first one appears to go to www.yoursite.com/Register, while the second (the one not working) goes to www.yoursite.com/Account/Register.. which one do you want.. ?

Comment: I want to go to /Account/Register.  After clicking either button the url says www.mysite.com/Account/Register.  The one that doesn't work gives me a white, blank screen, but the other one works fine

Comment: I suspect there's more going on here. Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: I added the controller code for both the Logon (get) and Register (get) Actions.  It's pretty basic...

Comment: I can't tell what's going on from what you've described and posted. My only advice would be to strip back pieces of code from your controllers, then your views, to determine the cause. Do you have any special routing?

Comment: I have not changed the default routing settings.  Can you give me an example of how you use @Html.BeginForm with JqueryMobile?  Or at least point me to an example on the internet?  I haven't seen one.  Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed you're including jquery.mobile after your script.. can you move it up above the script and try again? Also, your extension to $.mobile appears to not be in any script tags..

Comment: Oy vey!! you hit it.  As you pointed out, I missed the script tags around the script.  Once I added those, the rest worked. fyi, according to the docs, the $(document).bind() must happen before the Jquery Mobile script is included.